# .htaccess http to https not working

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

despite searching for previous answers, I couldn't see one which addresses my issue, so hope someone can help?

I recently redirected an old html company site to a new wordpress site with .htaccess rules (obvs different domain)

however, shortly afterwards I updated the new domain with an ssl cert. The old site was just a regular http:

I changed the .htaccess rules for the https: but obvs I have done it incorrectly as the redirect does not work.

this is what I am using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.co.uk$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.old-domain.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.com$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

what do I need to change to have it redirect correctly?

thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this variant for redirecting from `http` to `https`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also there are a lot of plugins for wordpress that help with that. They also help with redirecting all request to resources (images etc) to `https`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, the issue with wp plugins is the site with the 301 is a html site, so have to add the .htaccess rules in order to point to the wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```